# mysql is not available in django.db.backends (django)

Tags: python, mysql, django

trying to connect to the mysql and trying to do makemigrations. but getting this error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '****',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        "HOST": '****',
        'PORT': '****'
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to access MySQL db directly using the parameters you are using in Django?

Comment: Did you create an empty MySQL DB in advance, before trying to access it using Django?

Comment: @alv2017 yeah! I've created an empty MySQL DB and then, tried to access it in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by removing virtual environment and reinstalling all the packages again,
then you can have access to mysql database

Following the reinstalling packages advice, which worked for me:

```
pip uninstall -y `pip freeze`

pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If you do not have a requirements file already you can create it with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Comment: Rebuilding the entire virtualenv seems excessive.  Do you know why this fixes the issue?